# p:tree node select event listener method is not invoked

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 3.0.M4. I want to update the contents of PrimeFaces layout unit on tree node selection. I have added the following methods to my backing bean:

```
public void setSelectedNode(TreeNode selectedNode) {
   this.selectedNode = selectedNode;
   this.selectedNode.setSelected(true);
}

public void onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent e) {
   this.setSelectedNode(e.getTreeNode());
}
```

In the view I am using ajax to trigger the `onNodeSelect()` listener method:

```
<p:tree id="tree"  value="#{treeBean.root}" selection="#{treeBean.selectedNode}"     var="node" selectionMode="single" dynamic="true"  cache="false" >
  <p:ajax listener="#{treeBean.onNodeSelect}" update="test" event="select"/>
  <p:treeNode>
    <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>
  </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

Note: the tree is inside another PrimeFaces layout unit.

But when I run this, the `onNodeSelect()` method is not called at all. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Cleanup Engrish - brilliant! :D

Comment: @spauny sorry, i didn't get you...

Comment: @Tushar: try to ask questions the smart way, not the whining way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does it mean `update test`?

You should post your entire xhtml code! Also you should not try to update the entire layoutUnit but instead update your form (`update="myFormId"` or `update=":myFormId"`) or even a panel inside the form like this: `update=":myFormId:myPanelId"`.

Comment: ..sry for the incomplete code. Actually the "test" is the id of layoutunit:    <p:layoutUnit position="center" id="test">
                    <ui:include      src="${treeBean.selectedNode.name}.xhtml"/>
                </p:layoutUnit>,

 also I have tried updating the panelgroup. but it was no use.

Comment: ...Can you help me out in more more thing ...??

Comment: @TusharAgarwal Sure...Choose this as your accepted answer (that green check image) if you feel like and then ask another question(another topic)

Comment: @spauny...Thankx ...i have posted the question ..

[link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183403/primefaces-layoutunit-content-not-chaging-on-node-selction)